# Docker on Mac: No space left on device

Tags: docker, java-8

I am trying to build a base Docker image from Ubuntu 14.04 that installs Java 8. Here's what I have so far:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Me Myself <memyself@example.com>

WORKDIR /

RUN \
    echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer
```

When I run `docker build -t memyself/docker_sample .` I get the following error installing Java:

```
myuser@mymachine:~/sandbox/workspace/docker_sample$docker build -t memyself/docker_sample .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 127.1 MB
Step 0 : FROM ubuntu:14.04
 ---> 91e54dfb1179
Step 1 : MAINTAINER Me Myself <memyself@example.com>
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 070127f8f0e5
Step 2 : WORKDIR /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d2c8a7633d41
Step 3 : RUN echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select
true | debconf-set-selections &&   add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java &&
apt-get update &&   apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer &&   rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* &&   rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer
 ---> Running in 548fc192e112
/bin/sh: 1: add-apt-repository: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c echo oracle-java8-installer
shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections &&
add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java &&   apt-get update &&
apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer &&
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* &&   rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer'     
returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Any idea where I'm going awry?

---

#### Update:

I added the `apt-get install -y software-properties-common` line and now I'm getting an *enormous* amount of output, some of which is:

```
162816K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 93% 3.92M 2s
165888K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 95% 5.43M 1s
168960K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 97% 6.35M 1s
172032K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 98% 6.09M 0s
175104K ........ ........ ........ .....                     100% 5.27M=32s

2015-09-25 15:33:33 (5.43 MB/s) - 'jdk-8u60-linux-x64.tar.gz' saved [181238643/181238643]

Download done.
Removing outdated cached downloads...
tar: jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/charsets.jar: Wrote only 3072 of 10240 bytes
tar: jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/jce.jar: Cannot write: No space left on device
tar: jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/amd64/libbci.so: Cannot write: No space left on device
tar: jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/amd64/libjavafx_font_freetype.so: Cannot write: No space left on device
tar: jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/amd64/libawt_headless.so: Cannot write: No space left on device
tar: jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/amd64/libdt_socket.so: Cannot write: No space left on device
tar: jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/amd64/libmlib_image.so: Cannot write: No space left on device
...Huge amount of output omitted for brevity...
tar: jdk1.8.0_60/bin/jvisualvm: Cannot write: No space left on device
tar: jdk1.8.0_60/bin/jcontrol: Cannot write: No space left on device
tar: jdk1.8.0_60/release: Cannot write: No space left on device
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
cannot unpack jdk8
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
debconf: DbDriver "config": could not write /var/cache/debconf/config.dat-new: No space left on device
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up gsfonts (1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.2ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
    unable to flush /var/lib/dpkg/updates/tmp.i after padding: No space left on device
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

**It is important to note that if I try to start up more than a few other images (pulled from Docker Hub) on my Mac, I get similar "*No space left on device*" errors.** So I believe this latest problem is perhaps due to not allocating enough space for Docker on my machine (similar to a JVM `OutOfMemoryException` issue).

Comment: Please check whether there is enough space in your virtual machine. You can do so by ssh into the vm via `docker-machine ssh <machine-name>`. If you use the default installation of docker toolbox your machine name will be `default`. When you are in the machine you call `df -h`. The relevant output is the line starting with `/dev/sda1/`. If the value in column `Use%` is near to 100, your virtual disk is full. In that case you can start removing containers and images or increase the disk size. Please report back your findings.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your filesystem where docker stores its files is full. That's why tar chokes when unpacking the downloaded java archieve.

`docker info` will show you where the files are located, e.g.

```
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
```

`df -h` will tell you how much disk space is available on your filesystems.

Use `docker ps -a` to find containers that can be deleted and remove them with `docker rm -v` (`-v` is important because it also removes volumes).
Use `docker images` to find unneeded images and remove them with `docker rmi`.

You may have dangling image layers that are no longer needed. Delete them with `docker rmi $(docker images -q -f dangling=true)`.

Comment: Since Docker 1.9.0 there is also an api for removing unused volumes.
You can find them with `docker volume ls --filter dangling=true` and remove them with
`docker volume rm $(docker volume ls --filter dangling=true -q)`

Comment: Docker 1.13.0 added dedicated commands for housekeeping.

You can issue `docker image prune` and `docker volume prune` to delete unused ("dangling") images and volumes. There is also `docker system prune` which deletes stopped containers, unused volumes, unused networks and dangling images. 

The new commands ask for confirmation before actually deleting anything.

Comment: docker info lied to me, said Root Dir is /var/lib/docker, but that directory does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

try adding

```
apt-get install -y software-properties-common
```

to get `add-apt-repository`. Either in another `RUN` command or just before you use `add-apt-repository`.

Comment: Or add the repo manually.   Don't know if it's still true but that used to bring in a bunch of python crap.

Comment: Thanks @Robert (+1) - please see my updates, any ideas? Thanks again! I guess in general I'm just sort of *thunderstruck* that there isn't a standard Ubuntu 14.04 and JRE 8 Docker image out there...

Comment: @smeeb The official Java docker image is based on Debian. Close enough to Ubuntu. see: https://hub.docker.com/_/java/

Comment: @smeeb looks like `python-software-properties` is no longer required, but you should also add the `-y` flag. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Robert (+1) - please see my update that incorporates those changes. Getting "not enough space on disk" errors which is ridiculous (I have some 12GB disk avalable on my laptop).

Comment: Are you running Docker natively or through boot2docker?

Comment: Thanks @KevanAhlquist (+1) - I'm on Mac and running via Docker Toolbox

Comment: If you haven't seen the docs on increasing the disk size, [here they are](https://docs.docker.com/articles/b2d_volume_resize/)

Comment: Thanks @KevanAhlquist (+1) - I used Docker Toolbox (not boot2docker) - any documentation that is similar to that link you provided, but specific to Toolbox? Thanks again!

Comment: Docker-machine still uses boot2docker behind the scenes when you use the virtualbox driver, the vmdk lives at `/Users/username/.docker/machine/machines/machineName/disk.vmdk`. You can probably use Solution 2 to resize it.

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly because the Docker.qcow2 is full.

Check out the size of the following file

`ls -lah ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2`

There is an open issue on docker for mac relating to this file, which is a sparse image containing yo. See https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/371

I had the same issue and since I did not mind to rebuild my containers, I just deleted Docker.qcow2, restarted docker and it solved my problem. Handle with care especially if you have lots of images which you rely on and can not rebuild.

Comment: This file doesn't exist on my computer. I have a heavy `Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/Docker.raw` though